# Single TCP-CLOSE_WAIT connection brings down application till restart

Tags: tcp, rhel5, memory-usage, socket, memory

Recently found a behaviour where my application had a connection in TCP Close_wait state till the app was restarted (after about 5 hours).

But during this period the SUnreclaim space was also increasing constantly and went down on restart.

The application is runnning on a rhel5 os and Im not very familiar with the memory management system. Would appreciate if someone clould tell me what extactly is the Ureclaim space and why it is increasing in sync with the close_wait.

Comment: Sounds like bad behavior on the applications' part in that these type of requests are not set to timeout.

Comment: Sounds like the application is not closing its sockets.